# GDAL installation required for users?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gdal, java

I'm writing a little Java program to read some shapefiles & spit out the result of some calculations. I'm using GDAL, as the arcObjects.jar for ArcGIS Desktop is too restrictive for what I need (at least with my level of experience).

If I build a short Java program using GDAL imports, and I send as an .exe to my users, must my users ALSO install GDAL on their computers in order to be able to use the program? The users in question currently use ArcGIS Desktop, but not GDAL.

Comment: If the users currently have ArcGIS licenses, your Java ArcObjects tool would leverage their seat, not yours; therefore, how could this be restrictive? Not that Esri also uses GDAL in places, so libraries are available on each workstation (though maybe not fully available for your purpose).

Comment: ArcGIS Desktop is too restrictive. Not GDAL (as far as I know). In my specific scenario, I wasn't aware that the arcobjects jar is incompatibile with Apach POI jars for building excel workbooks. But, too late. I already designed my program to build an Excel Workbook, and behold: they're incompatible.
My concern is about building a GDAL-based program and whether or not my users will have access to its use.